# Origin of "on" to mean "powered"

Tags: etymology

When did the word "on" start to mean "powered"? An example of this would be "The lights are on."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An early attestation of *on* meaning something like *activating another thing* comes from the fifteenth century poem *[The Tale of Ralph the Collier](https://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/lupack-three-middle-english-charlemagne-romances-tale-of-ralph-collier#f12)*, line 107:

> *Dame, kyith I am cummin hame, and kendill on ane fyre;*
>
> Dame, know I am coming home, and kindle on a fire

"Kindle on," "bring on," and similar verb phrases would use "on" to mean, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, "[on, adv., adj, and n.1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131296)," 11a, "Into action or operation; so as to function; so as to be activated or brought about." This meaning is independent of any kind of electrical power, and perhaps also influenced other meanings, like being *on* for a performance.

In the nineteenth century, "on" was applied to early powered technologies like steam, gas, and water. Here is one description of using gas to turn up the lights from an 1834 book by Harriet Martineau titled [*The Loom and the Lugger*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ozxXAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA10&lpg=RA1-PA10&dq=%22He%20turned%20on%20the%20gas%20in%20his%20back%20room%20to%20an%20unusual%20brightness.%22&source=bl&ots=tYjM2icxja&sig=ACfU3U0LoMt05252GqCC2b-1Z0mIHH5ttA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjczay-ruHgAhUhneAKHS4_C-0Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22He%20turned%20on%20the%20gas%20in%20his%20back%20room%20to%20an%20unusual%20brightness.%22&f=false), p. 10:

> He turned on the gas in his back room to an unusual brightness.

The Oxford English Dictionary explains this instance under *turn on*, under "[turn, v.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/207669)", as "induc(ing) a flow of (water, steam, gas, electric current) by turning a tap or stop-cock ... or by opening a sluice.

From here, the preposition generalized from a preposition associated with a verb into an adjective to describe the state of something powered. By the end of the century, this meaning of *on* was appearing either in extraposition from the verb or independently of the verb. Here's [an example from 1892](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Chambers_s_Journal/reIXAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=We%20turned%20our%20lanterns%20full%20on.&pg=PA367&printsec=frontcover), where *on* is an adjective modified by *full*:

> We turned our lanterns full on.

And here in *[Fire and Water](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fire_and_Water/cVzTGeCNM9oC?hl=en&gbpv=1)* from 1896 in abbreviated notation is *on* without a verb:

> Water pressure on
>
> Gas on and door closed

Answer (score 0):

It started the minute there was a switch to turn it 'on'.  As soon as the switch was flicked, it was either 'on' or 'off'.

Switched on, powered on, turned on; the common denominator is 'on'.

Switches to provide power to a device always had an 'on' switch.  On was used when the contacts in the switch were physically in contact with (on) each other, hence 'on' for power.

Comment: Right, but I think OP is asking: why *on* in particular? Why don't we say "switched in" or "switched through", etc?

Comment: I think this answer could also address other items that can be turned on. Why a switch instead of a valve, when valves would have been used in gas lanterns?

Comment: This is completely circular. The only reason we switch something _on_ is because when something is powered, we say that it’s ‘on’. Note that in most other languages I can think of, equivalents to ‘on’ and ‘off’ are **not** used in this context. Additionally, there are instances of _on_ (especially with a preceding verb) which predate the electric switch.